# Размер страницы PDF через PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf

Есть pdf - файл, который содержит следующие листы формата высота х ширина

> A4 297x210  А4 297х210 А2х3 594х1260 А3х4 420х1188 А3 297х420

Я использую скрипт на python и библиотеку PyPDF2, чтобы получить параметры высоты и ширины каждого листа:

```
with open(path, 'rb') as pdf_file:
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            box = pdf_reader.getPage(i)
            width = int(float(box.mediaBox.getWidth())*0.3527)
            height = int(float(box.mediaBox.getHeight())*0.3527)
            value.append([height, width])
            i += 1
        except Exception:
            break
```

Получаю следующий вывод:

> [297, 210][297, 210]**[1260, 594][1188, 420]**[297, 420]

Как видно, только в двух случаях параметры ширины и высоты меняются местами, что для меня критично
В чем проблема ? Как это исправить ?

Comment: возможно, стоит проверять ориентацию страниц? Через метод `.get('/Rotate')`?

Comment: strawdog, спасибо. Помогло